# Azure Stream Analytics Query

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I would like to write the following json string with Stream Anaytics into a SQL Database every Minute.

```
{
  "time": "2018-06-05T11:00:00Z",
  "deviceId": 10,
  "val": [ 200, 250, 300, 201, 501, 250, 890 ]
}
```

The Database has Columns "time","deviceId", 7 Columns for the Values.

My Query:

```
WITH seperate AS(
SELECT
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime AS Time,
    deviceId,
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 0)) AS '0',
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 1)) AS '1'
FROM
    Input
GROUP BY 
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    deviceId,
    TumblingWindow(minute, 1)
)
SELECT * INTO Output1 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 1
SELECT * INTO Output2 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 2
SELECT * INTO Output3 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 3
SELECT * INTO Output4 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 4
SELECT * INTO Output5 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 5
```

here i have the problem that update the database all minute with all Values (6-from every 10 sek)
i want every minute one Database Row

second thing is there another way to write the array values (without write AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 0)) AS '0',
AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 1)) AS '1',
....

Comment: You have a database per device or why are you using multiple outputs?

Comment: As per my answer, there is afaik no way to do what you want without writing out all GetArrayElement statements. Not if you want to have them in a single database row.

Comment: i have one Database but per Device a separately table. okay then i do it with the GetArrayElement) can you helb me with the 6values per Minute? i want one

Answer (score 0):

`GetArrayElement` is your friend. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getarrayelement-azure-stream-analytics)

```
SELECT
    time,
    deviceId,
    GetArrayElement(val, 0) AS FirstElement,
    GetArrayElement(val, 1) AS SecondElement
    … and so on
INTO
    Output
FROM
    IotHub
```

You indicate that the data comes from a IOT hub every 10 seconds, and the data stored should be the "raw" datas. But you also want the data to be written to the database every minute. Then you will have to aggregate data or store it in the database directly.

You cannot use Azure Stream Analytics to buffer the incoming data and then write a 6 records to the database every minute.

You can apply [windowing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/windowing-azure-stream-analytics) per minute but then the data will be aggregated during the time of the window. For example, 
you can store the average values of the array every minute.

If you want the raw values you cannot apply windowing and you have to write them to the database when the data comes in (which is every 10 seconds)

A windows query could be something like

```
SELECT
    deviceId,
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 0)) AS AvgFirstElement,
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 1)) AS AvgSecondElement
    … and so on
INTO
    Output
FROM
    IotHub
GROUP BY 
    deviceId, 
    TumblingWindow(minute, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, okay with this Query i become the first Element, but i want all Elements and that every minute.

Comment: You can of course add more.. you want them in a single row in sql isn't?

Comment: @MarkusWimmer You want the query to send it every minute? So I can assume the input stream delivers more events in a minute? What do you want to do with the data, sum it? Also, what is the point of including `time` in the query when more than one event comes in per minute but you want the data written per minute?

Comment: @MarkusWimmer do you want the data to be written once a minute per deviceId?

Comment: Yes it is a Single Row, the Events come from a IOT hub every 10seconds, the data should be the "raw" datas.

Comment: @MarkusWimmer Then why the need to write it every minute to the DB if the data rate is every 10 seconds? Why not just write it after it comes in? You can use [windowing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/windowing-azure-stream-analytics) but then the data will be aggregated. And you want the raw data.

Comment: @MarkusWimmer I have updated my answer to show how a windowing query would look like.

Comment: Peter Thanks, okay for testing i have 7 Values, but later it will be 1000, so i really have to write all the Array elements in the Query? the 1000 values are the reason why every minute... can you please post an example querey with this windowing and the avg, you can see i have a "deviceID", i have 5Devices on a IOT Hub over this Device id i want to write Data in different Outputs but only when the device id equals...

Comment: `WITH seperate AS(
SELECT
    time,
    deviceId,
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 0)) AS '0',
    AVG(GetArrayElement(val, 1)) AS '1'
FROM
    Input
GROUP BY 
    time,
    deviceId,
    TumblingWindow(minute, 1)
)
SELECT * INTO Output1 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 1
SELECT * INTO Output2 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 2
SELECT * INTO Output3 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 3
SELECT * INTO Output4 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 4
SELECT * INTO Output5 FROM seperate WHERE deviceId = 5` is there another way to get the Array elements?

Comment: Please consider using CollectTOP aggregate function if you need to capture top N raw events per time window. For example, you can get 10 most recent events by using CollectTop(10) OVER (ORDER BY time)

Comment: @MarkusWimmer, if you don't mind that each array value will be a separate record in the database you could use [cross apply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getarrayelements-azure-stream-analytics)

Comment: Buit could you update your question to add as much details as needed as that makes it easier to read for others as well. And can you describe your desired output in terms of resulting rows better?